# How to see available wireless networks on 12.10?

Tags: wireless, setup

I'm using a Dell Inspiron laptop with Ubuntu 12.10. I am new to Linux.

I am typing this from a wired connection because I cannot find how to set up my wireless router. When I first installed 12.10 it gave me a men in the install wizard to set up WiFi but when I restarted it turned off. I cannot figure out how to get wireless, or to see available wireless routers.

WiFi is on and works with my iPad but I literally cannot find the place to enable WiFi on this OS. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the `nm-applet` hanging. I've had problems with it listing the available networks right after login. The solution is to kill and restart it.

```
sudo killall nm-applet && nm-applet &
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your wifi hardware switch is on or not. It is either F2 or F12 or near to it. Once the switch is enabled, there is a small fan-like applet on the top panel (Gnome Network Manager), fourth from the right.

[image]

Click on it and if there is no tick mark on the option 'Enable Wireless', enable it. Wait till your wifi connection name appears.